# After writing to a text file using c++ there are only some unreadable characters in that file

Tags: c++, pointers, file-handling

I wrote a program to write some integers to a text file using c++. But after running the code, there are only some unreadable characters inside the text file.

How do I fix it?

My code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("my.txt","w");

    for (int i =1; i<= 10; i++){
      putw(i, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This is how it shows the text file after running the code above.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqOxs.jpg

Comment: Integers from 1 to 10 correspond to non-readable characters in the [ASCII table](https://www.alpharithms.com/s3/assets/img/ascii-chart/ascii-table-alpharithms-scaled.jpg). You first need to convert the integer into its ASCII representation using, for instance, a function such as [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: And you expected ASCII values from 1-10 to be what exactly? https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `<iostream>` is the wrong header for the functions you are using, `putw` is not standard C++ or C at all and none of these functions are commonly used in C++. Where did you learn to write C++ like this? You should be using `std::fstream` and `<<`.

Comment: @user17732522 No, he shouldn't. His code is beginner-quality code but otherwise it's fine. C++ is almost wholly backward-compatible with C for a reason. He can learn those other things later.

Comment: @Pramo user17732522 does have a point regarding the header, though.  The right header for `putw()` is `<cstdio>`.  We got lucky in that, apparently, `<iostream>` pulls in `<cstdio>` incidentally on your and my systems.  The `<iostream>` is the proper eader for `cout` and other entities of that sort.

Comment: @thb I don't want to get into the whole discussion about teaching C when teaching C++, but `putw` is not even POSIX and the glibc man page even recommends not using it. Whether in a C++ course or in a C course, why would that function be taught to a beginner?

Comment: @user17732522 Now that you mention it, I see the notice in glibc to which you refer. So `putw` is probably not ideal even *if* one is approaching C++ on the C front, as you say. Perhaps like you, I have not used a function like `putw`, myself, in 15 or 20 years, except once or twice while maintaining very old code. Some years ago though I had occasion to teach introductory C++ as adjunct at a U.S. university and, in that context, sometimes found it helpful to overlook a beginning student's offbeat choice of library call. This is what I had in mind.

Comment: @user17732522 So my answer needs to be edited, at least, to warn future readers that its coding style is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after running the code, there are only some **unreadable characters** inside the text file. How do I fix it? ... This is how it shows the **text file** after running the code

The problem is that you expect it to be a text file, but `putw` writes the `int`s to the file in *binary* format.

In order to get readable characters in a text file, use the `std::fprintf` function instead of `putw`.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>  // This is correct header for `fopen`

int main(){
    std::FILE* fp = std::fopen("my.txt", "w");
    if (fp) {
        for (int i =1; i<= 10; i++){
            std::fprintf(fp, "%d", i);
        }
        std::fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

The C++ way to do the same thing would be to use `fstream`s:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream fs("my.txt");
    if (fs) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            fs << i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and the answer takes some thought and experimentation for a beginner to grasp.  Your program actually does write the numbers 1 through 10 into *my.txt*, but in binary form.  To prove this, try compiling and running the following, second program, which reads from the file the numbers your first program has written to the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("my.txt","r");

    for (int i =1; i<= 10; i++){
        const int m = getw(fp);
        cout << m << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

To be readable in text form, the numbers would want to have been written to the file in ASCII (a subset of UTF-8-encoded Unicode).  However, binary may be a reasonable or even a superior way to represent data like yours, depending on the application.

Because future readers may study this answer I should point out that the answer's code's style mimics your code's style to make the answer easier for you to understand.  Otherwise, the code would be written in a more standard, more modern C++ style and would look rather different.  To model future code on this answer therefore is not recommended.